# Argument type of parameterized method call in EL

Tags: el

I was making a method call `objectMapper.writeValueAsString` in EL like this.

```
<%@ attribute name="actionItems" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" type="java.util.List"%>
<jsp:useBean id="objectMapper"     class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper" scope="page" />
<jsp:useBean id="actionItemsMap" class="java.util.HashMap" />
<c:set target="${actionItemsMap}" property="actionItems"         value="${objectMapper.writeValueAsString(actionItems)}" />
```

`writeValueAsString` takes an Object parameter in [method signature](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#writeValueAsString(java.lang.Object)). It was working when I pass in `actionItems` which is an `ArrayList`.

Now I am upgrading my ApacheTomcat 7 from 7.0.52 to 7.0.70, and the code is broken with `MethodNotFoundException`:

> javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(java.util.ArrayList)
>   at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:422)
>   at org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.invoke(JasperELResolver.java:139)

It is trying to find a method `writeValueAsString` with argument type `ArrayList`. It seems related to [this change](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55483) in 7.0.53. How should I change my code to make it work? Do I have to make the method call with an Object argument? If so, is there a way I can cast the `ArrayList` to an Object in EL and then make the method call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is an issue on our side. These parameterized method calls are supported.